# What is the Difference Between an Android Phone and Android Tablet?

Tags: tablet

This is probably a dumb question, but I have never had a phone or tablet before.

So what is the difference between a tablet and phone?

From what I can see the tablets do not come with the monthly data plans (so are cheaper).

1. But is there a sim card slot in a tablet if you want one?
2. Do all tablets have WiFi so I can link to my home broadband router. (I found out today that phones do - that shows you how green I am.)
3. Do they all come with a usb slot?
4. Can tablets and phones both do Google Play?

From what I can tell the APK files will work on phones and tablets (provided the apk can cope with the different screen resolutions).

Is there any difference?

Comment: **Size** is the main difference. Mobiles fit into your pocket while tablets don't. As a general rule, you can do everything that you can on a tablet which you can do on a phone (camera is noticeably low end on tablet). But for all the features you need on a phone you would need to spend more. Define your need and Google

Comment: The ability to make a phone call is the main difference and I'm not talking VoIP. You won't find anyone using a tablet to make phone calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions that ask several other questions aren't the best format for Stack Exchange, but I'll answer these anyway.

> But is there a sim card slot in a tablet if you want one?

Depends on the model. Some do, <s>but these are obviously used for just data</s> and this can be used for internet access when outside of a Wi-Fi zone. Many mobile networks provide data-only SIM cards that are just used for internet which are perfect for tablets, but if you get a full SIM, with texting and calling, you'll be able to text but have a difficult time with making calls (I don't think most tablets even come with a dialer app?)

> Do all tablets have WiFi so I can link to my home broadband router. (I found out today that phones do - that shows you how green I am.)

I think it's safe to say that all tablets aimed towards the average consumer have Wi-Fi built into them. ;^)

Just read the specs of the tablet before you buy it and you'll be fine.

> Do they all come with a usb slot?

Again, it depends on the model, but all have some way to connect them to a charger. Micro-USB and USB Type-C ports are commonplace nowadays.

> Can tablets and phones both do Google Play?

Yes assuming that the manufacturer installs it in the first place. The only time you'll not find it is on Amazon Fire devices, specialist devices, and in countries which prohibit Google Play due to laws or whatever. There are ways to install Google Play yourself though.